# Unable to mock request to Auth0 using json-server

Tags: angular, proxy, protractor, auth0, json-server

[image]

We are using Auth0 as authentication service provider for our angular SPA and we are using auth0-spa-js library from Auth0.

We are trying to setup our frontend e2e(functional) tests using protractor and we want to mock out the authentication calls to Auth0.

> **So we now have 3 domains: `localhost:4200` as our application domain, `localhost:3010` for our proxy server and our auth0 domain**

*Since mock modules is not yet supported in Angular*, the only way to mock authentication is to proxy the authentication API calls made to the auth0 domain and redirect them to our mock server.

We are trying to redirect the `https://myAuth0Domain/authorize` call made to Auth0 using the auth0-spa-js to a proxy server to fetch the mocked response by defining configuration through proxy config.

We have setup mockServer using JsonServer library.

We have configured json-server on `localhost:3010`, 
We have setup proxy config as below.

On navigating directly using Postman to `localhost:3010/path/to/response` we are able to see the mocked response even during the serve.

So it seems that the proxy server is listening correctly.
However, while running the e2e tests, the API call is not being proxied.

How can we mock this API call made to auth0 domain to our proxy server to get the response to get the user authenticated and redirect back to our application?

**Our Mock.json**

```
{
    "path/to/response": [
        {
            "status": "302",
            "location": "http://localhost:4200/callback",
            "access_token": "Mock_Access_Token",
            "expires_in": 8600,
            "id_token": "Some_id_Token",
            "scope": "openid profile email",
            "token_type:": "Bearer",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Our proxy.config.js**

```
var proxyConfig = [
  {
    context: "https://myAuth0Domain.com/authorize",
    target: "http://localhost:3010/path/to/response",
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
  }
]
```

> we are using concurrently to run our e2e-test and json server at the same time

[image]